# Ansible - parse values from multiple lists in loop

Tags: loops, ansible, json-query

So I have been scratching my head and I think the solution is easy but can not see the light :-)

I have this code which reads the registry and gets the MSSQL names:

```
- name: check for instances
   win_reg_stat:
     path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
   register: instance_output
```

I then get the services running for them:

```
- name: get the services
   ansible.windows.win_service_info:
     name: MSSQL*
   register: service_output
   failed_when: service_output is not defined
```

in my debug i am joining the 2 sets:

```
- name: debug
   debug: 
     msg:
       - "{{ item }}"
   loop:
     - "{{ instance_output.properties.InstalledInstances.value | zip (service_output| json_query('services[*].start_mode')) | list }}"
```

and  i get the data:

```
[
   [
     "db1",
     "manual"
   ],
   [
     "db2",
     "auto"
   ],
   [
     "db3",
     "disabled"
   ]
 ]
```

The number of dbs can be anything, so I can not use item.0, item.1, and item.2

My question is this ... how can set up a when clause where start_mode is not disabled?

I have tried with_items, however I am using ansible 2.15.3 so I know sooner or later with_items will not work...

I have tried flatten,

but I am essentially trying to get the return of db1 and db2 to continue the next part of the tasks.

Here is a snippet of one service_output

```
{
                    "checkpoint": 0,
                    "controls_accepted": [
                        "stop",
                        "pause_continue",
                        "shutdown"
                    ],
                    "dependencies": [],
                    "dependency_of": [
                        "SQLAgent$db1"
                    ],
                    "description": "",
                    "desktop_interact": false,
                    "display_name": "db1",
                    "error_control": "normal",
                    "failure_actions": [],
                    "failure_actions_on_non_crash_failure": false,
                    "failure_command": null,
                    "failure_reboot_msg": null,
                    "failure_reset_period_sec": 0,
                    "launch_protection": "",
                    "load_order_group": "",
                    "name": "MSSQL$db1",
                    "path": "\"D:\\",
                    "pre_shutdown_timeout_ms": 1,
                    "preferred_node": null,
                    "process_id": 4300,
                    "required_privileges": [],
                    "service_exit_code": 0,
                    "service_flags": [],
                    "service_type": "",
                    "sid_info": "",
                    "start_mode": "manual",
                    "state": "",
                    "triggers": [],
                    "username": "",
                    "wait_hint_ms": 0,
                    "win32_exit_code": 0
                }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your service_output so one could have a look into a solution with map or sellectattr?

Comment: Hi @U880D I have added a snippet from the service_output (only db1).  Thanks